# How to convert a complex curve with depth into a clean mesh without overlapping faces?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, bezier-curves, vertices, faces

I modeled a hexagonal grid mesh of interconnected vertices and edges which I converted into a curve via <kbd>RMB</kbd> *> Convert To > Curve* and gave it a [`Geometry Bevel`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/curves/properties/geometry.html) depth of 0.25m and resolution of 1 which resulted in this nice thick hexagonal grid shape.

[image]

But when I convert it into a mesh with <kbd>RMB</kbd> *> Convert To > Mesh*, it gives me an unclean mesh with overlapping faces as shown in the left image which would give me problems when adding modifiers such as subdivision or bevel. How do I get a clean mesh such as the one on the right or any other clean mesh with connected faces? I got this mesh through manual/tedious editing. Is that even possible or should I avoid this "mesh to curve" and then "curve to mesh" process?

[image]

Comment: I would only model the inner part of one hex grid element as shown on the right in the 2nd screenshot. And then, create the grid from this part only. Except you want to have it fully procedural and customizable for some reason, of course.

Comment: @Blunder hey thank you for your response. Yeah in this scenario that would actually work perfectly, thank you! But I had more complex shapes like [this shape in this thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/280411/how-to-subdivide-this-n-gon-shape-to-avoid-artifacts) where I had to use the "mesh to curve" then *curve to mesh" process and which yielded into the same overlapping faces problem at adjoining curve vertices.