# How can I fill a complex face with good topology?

Tags: mesh, topology

As shown below, I've got a complex shape/loop (340 verts) which I'm using as the base shape of some scaly hide/skin. I need to fill this with a dense mesh so it can be deformed with a lattice (to create folds and drape over a shield), and then have details sculpted into it using VDM brushes.

[image]

The issue is, I can't work out how to fill the shape properly with good topology and which can be subdivided without artifacts. A few methods I've tried:

1. Creating face topology by hand - far too time consuming, and liable to errors.
2. Grid fill - as it's a single, conjoined loop, Blender won't grid fill the shape
3. Filling as an n-gon, then insetting faces to get even edgeloops. This worked - for two insets. Then the protruding parts of the shape got too narrow to inset.
4. Filling as an n-gon, then using knife project to cut a grid into it. This is the most successful method I've used, but the grid leaves tris and n-gons along the edges, which produce artifacts after applying solidify and sub-div surface modifiers as per the below images. These artifacts are hard to eliminate even using dynotopo smoothing, and mean I can't get sharp edges to the hide/skin (which are preferable for my purposes).
   [image]
   [image]

So, is there a reliable way to fill a shape like this with an even mesh? If not, is there an alternative method/workflow I could use to achieve the desired outcome?

For context, I'm just using vanilla blender at the moment.

EDIT: Blend file uploaded: [image]

Comment: You can remesh it. Have you tried remeshing? Quad Remesher is really good but unfortunately it is paid version.

Comment: Have you tried to remesh in Sculpt mode (which is actually the same as the Object Data > Remesh >Quad) then smooth the edges with the Smooth brush? Maybe share your file so that we can give a try

Comment: Or please check my new answer

Comment: @Moonboots - Thanks for the assistance, much appreciated. I've not got time to test your new answer now, but looks promising, so thanks very much. I've uploaded the blend file if you want to see what I'm working with.
I did try remeshing using blenders QuadRemesher tool, but found it to be very inconsistent and lumpy. That said, maybe I need to play with the settings and add more subdivisions

Comment: Update: @moonboots - thanks again. Tested your solution earlier and it's given me exactly what I needed! Marked as answered now.

Comment: oh ok great then   ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try this way, first inset slightly the face (if you have too many vertices it may be better to remove some with the <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve* operation):

[image]

Hide the outer vertices, cut a grid with the *Knife Project* tool:

[image]

Unhide the outer vertices:

[image]

Extrude up the whole mesh:

[image]

Bevel the edges, create horizontal edge loops, the mesh should be ready for *Lattice* deformation and *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]

Comment: so it's a duplicate question to https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/280411/how-to-subdivide-this-n-gon-shape-to-avoid-artifacts?

Comment: Yes it looks like ;)

Comment: i was struggling with this type of problem as well and only found this solution haha but still cool, but the Quad Remesher is also really awesome, it's unfortunately paid version though :(

Comment: Does it keep the edgez clean?

Comment: Instant Mesh is free though, i haven't tried for this shape

Comment: yeah it is super powerful. like this 2000 faces https://snipboard.io/iwOXTZ.jpg or this https://snipboard.io/tGX0K8.jpg 5000 faces

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not a duplicate. The other user in that question was satisfied with using knife project. However, as per point 4 in my original question, I stated I'd already tried knife project, but the tris and n-gons the grid leaves at the shape's edge creates artifacts which cannot be smoothed out once it is solidified.

Furthermore, unlike the previous user's question, my loop has an even number of vertices (340, as stated in my question), but won't grid fill.

Appreciate the suggestion of quad remesher. I tried blender's inbuilt one, but may need to give it another try.