How to subdivide many complex meshes?
I created a globe. Each country has its own mesh, because I need it like this for an app development. 
Currently, all meshes are big n-gones, which is not great for the deformation. Now, I am searching for a way to subdivide the meshes. I was already successful using the knife tool. But in this case, I need to create a plane, go in the edit mode... And I need to do it for over 200 meshes.
Maybe, somebody has some experience and knows how to do it in a faster way.
If I triangulate the faces and use the subdivision modifier, I does not look great, because of the edges.

One idea is to create a flat subdivided cube in the geometry nodes I am using. And afterwards lay it on country mesh and use the boolean node to receive a copy, which is subdivided and has the same transformation. But I do not know how to do it.

Unfortunately that will not be an easy task. Mostly manual work. Or you could try remeshers like Quad Remesher (really good but paid addon) or the free built-in Quadriflow Remesher but is not so good.

There's also the software called Instant Meshes but maybe share your file so that we can give a try (share only a part of it)?

@moonboots You can get the meshes from the file in his last question.

@Gordon Brinkmann Oh ok thanks  ;)

@HarryMcKenzie I tried Quad Remesher. It is good, but not perfect enough. I have gaps at the borders. Unfortunately, the knife tool was still the best.

@PascalMeger yeah I had exactly the same question https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/280411/how-to-subdivide-this-n-gon-shape-to-avoid-artifacts so I guess this is a duplicate so i voted to close as duplicate.

Does this answer your question? How to subdivide this n-gon shape to avoid artifacts?

Not really, I think I need to use the knife 250 times manually :D

You can use Control + T to triangulate all faces selected, instead of manually using the knife tool.


This will convert all faces to tris, removing any n-gons.
Then, a subdivision surface modifier should work just fine for any farther geometry you need.  Make sure to set it to "Simple", or it will erode the edges of your meshes.
Hope this is helpful!

Problem is, that it creates many edges near to next other, which causes deformations.

Deformations, as in, animated?

I added a picture with the deformations in the text above.

@PascalMeger If these are still the same meshes from your last question, triangulating will help absolutely nothing here - because they are already triangulated, just in very large and useless triangles. Together they have 90,537 faces and 90,537 triangles, so there are no quads or n-gons, all tris. And after triangulating with Ctrl+T the number of tris is still 90,537.

@GordonBrinkmann should I delete my answer?
